# Are there any works on $\int^{z_1}_{z_2}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\;f(t) \;dt$?

Tags: integration, beta-function

Beta function is defined as $B(x,y)= \int^{1}_{0} t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} \;dt$. I wonder are there any works on $\int^{z_1}_{z_2}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\;f(t) \;dt$ where $f(t)$ is any arbitrary function. If not, is this easily solved? What method would you use to solve this? By part?

Comment: Already with $f=1$, the name Beta function was put because it not possible to simplify it ... So of course there is no simplification for general $f$ ...

Comment: @LL3.14 The beta function has an expression in gamma functions. So I think this is a valid question.

Comment: Yes, but this is just another special function ... it depends on what is the meaning of "is this easily solved?"
But I agree that to know if there are works on this kind of integral transforms is interesting! I was just replying to the fact that in any case there is no easy way to "solve" this integral with usual functions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is the sum of a power series $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ with radius of convergence $>1$, then your integral is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n B(a+n, b) = \Gamma(b) \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(a+b+n)}$$

Comment: This is quite an interesting answer. Nevertheless, imo, it is still a form of the beta function because $\int^{z_1}_{z_2}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n t^n dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \int^{z_1}_{z_2}t^{a+n-1}(1-t)^{b-1} \; dt$. I think it will be more interesting if $f(t)$ cannot be taken out from the integral and still have a nice solution.